# sdkman changed leiningen, clojure path variable

Tags: groovy, clojure, maven-2, leiningen, sdkman

I've installed the `groovy` language via the recommended `sdkman` package and somehow the path for `leiningen` has messed up i.e. I can no longer do something like

`(import '[clojure.string :as string])`

without raising the following error

`ClassNotFoundException clojure.string.:as  java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:381)`

The basic `lein repl` command is working fine otherwise but clojure is native-java libs only. How to correct this behavior?

Comment: Sure you didn't update something else? Can't see how this can happen...

Comment: Hey, @tim_yates I solved it and the solution is written below :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, turns out it was a classPath problem *and* the wrong way to import as an alias so I just had to go to `.groovy/conf` and add the local `~/.m2/**/*.jar` to the startup settings. Sovled :)